# Converting BigInt to timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table, in this table I have a column which currently stores a value of type `BigInt`, I want to alter this column to contain 'timestamp' values instead.

How can I achieve this. I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE t
MODIFY c TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

For which I get:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1524120113' for column 'created_temp' at row 1
```

And

```
ALTER TABLE share ADD created_temp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE share SET created_temp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created);
```

For which I get: `#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1524120113'`

The content of `created` is created using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got the first error because the DBMS cannot convert the column on the fly. The second error comes from the fact that [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) expects a `DATE`, `TIME` or `TIMESTAMP` *string* instead of integer so you should instead use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` documentation has an important note on the difference between the two functions:

> If you use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert between TIMESTAMP values and Unix timestamp values, the conversion is lossy because the mapping is not one-to-one in both directions. For example, due to conventions for local time zone changes, it is possible for two UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to map two TIMESTAMP values to the same Unix timestamp value. FROM_UNIXTIME() will map that value back to only one of the original TIMESTAMP values.

--

Here's the steps you need to do the task (**it can take a long time to complete because all rows will have to be rewritten!**):

1. Add a new column to your database:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD new_column TIMESTAMP NULL; 
   -- PS: You might want to use a default value instead of NULL here.
   ```
2. Convert the old values and fill the new column with them:

   ```sql
   UPDATE mytable SET new_column = FROM_UNIXTIME(old_column) WHERE old_column IS NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Delete the old column:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN old_column;
   ```
4. Rename the new column to the old name:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE new_column old_column;
   ```

Comment: In my case, timestamp was in milliseconds and so i had to apply FROM_UNIXTIME(old_column/1000);

Answer (score 12):

For instance, say that you have the timestamp `1376750476349` and you want to convert it into date time. You could simply do the following if your timestamp is in `seconds`.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_value);
```

however, and this is a recurrent problem for many users of the above function, if your timestamp is say in `milliseconds`, you will have to perform the required conversions to seconds` before using the function. So, in the case where the timestamp is in milliseconds you could do the following to get the datetime:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_value/1000);
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy!

[source](https://intelligea.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/how-to-convert-big-int-timestamp-into-system-date-in-mysql/)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to do this as a multi-step operation:

- Add a new column to your database.
- Populate it with the converted value.
- Remove the old column.

I'd *strongly* recommend using `DATETIME` in preference to `TIMESTAMP` because the `TIMESTAMP` column only works until 2038 and then explodes.

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` does not refer to a `TIMESTAMP` column, though they're tangentially related in that the `TIMESTAMP` type is a wrapper around a `time_t` type UNIX "timestamp" value, hence [the 2038 limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: Which is what I am trying to do in the second option but I get an error :)